# Sitecore XBlog get blog posts sort by Publish Date

Tags: sorting, sitecore, blogs

Default behaviour of BlogManager method GetBlogPosts is to return all posts that are sorted by Publish Date, in code it sorts before returning as below. But I don't get results sorted by Publish Date (which is field of Blog Post template).

```
var result = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(predicate)
.OrderByDescending(t => t[XBSettings.XBSearchPublishDate])
.Slice(startRowIndex, maximumRows)
.CreateAs<BlogPost>().ToList();
```

I tried to do it by adding Publish Date field to index config but no luck, need help how can I configure that I get results in descending order based on Publish Date field of Blog Post template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your index and see what the name of the Publish Date field is in the index. In some cases (when using solr), I have had to change that value to "published_date_tdt"

Comment: I did't find any field with name like publish date, by default there is no publish date in xblog index configurations

Comment: I examine the index using Luke, for some reasons publish_date field was not listed.  I deleted index files manually in data/indexes/blog_index folder and re-indexed.  I found publish_date field as indexed and updated my code, it works.